# Sound muting automatically in Windows 8.1

Tags: audio, drivers, windows-8.1

I've got a Windows 8.1 machine running on Gigabyte B85M-D3H Motherboard with a Realtek chipset for Audio.

For the last few weeks, the sound has been fading out across the whole OS on a regular basis.  The volume mixer behaves as if sound were playing and after clicking on the mixer volume slider a couple of times the sound will come back for a short time.

I've refreshed the BIOS, the chipset drivers and the realtek drivers to their latest versions.

Comment: I've found a question with similar symptoms but no resolution there either http://superuser.com/questions/695465/windows-7-sound-is-intermittently-dropping?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after all this time, I found out what the problem was. The JBL speakers that we had connected to the computer had a built in ***feature*** that would actually turn the speakers off if there was no signal coming in.  It was supposed to be 30 seconds, but any time the signal hit 0 the speakers would turn off and then take about 10 seconds to cycle back up to full volume.

Answer (score 2):

The windows 8 version is having a feature to automatically mute all sounds when communication activity is detected. In order to deactivate this feature

```
Open the Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Sound
Go to the Communication tab.
Select "Do nothing" and then click on OK to validate.
```

If you are facing any issues after changing the settings. Kindly download automatic diagnoser and check.

http://support2.microsoft.com/mats/audio-playback-windows-8/en-us

Comment: I saw that on a different web site and have already changed the setting, but it is still doing the mute.  I've unset and reset that setting several times.

Comment: Tried the audio troubleshooter with no luck.